# Change languages for specific apps

Tags: applications, languages

A week ago I was surprised with an update of an app that suddenly changed its language from English to my local language. This kind of change is usually good for most people, however, I would like to have the option to change it back, since I was used to the English therms the app was using...

Is there a way to change it back for this app (or, maybe, select apps that would be in English) without changing the whole phone language?

This specific app does not provide an UI (or any way to provide specific configuration) where I could select the language I want (I also don't know any app that has that kind of configuration option inside it)...

Comment: Not sure if it still works (hasn't been updated for ~3 years), and might need root: [AppConfig](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fi.aarosoft.appconfig.free) advertises that, amongst other things.

Comment: Go to that app settings and see if there is option to change language for it.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје in the last paragraph you can read: "_This specific app does not provide an UI (or any way to provide specific configuration) where I could select the language I want_"

Comment: @Izzy That should be a nice app. However, I've seen a comment from an user there, that said the app stopped working  on Android 5.02. I'm using 7 - I guess it won't work, unfortunately...

Comment: Yes, it hasn't been updated for a while – and unfortunately I couldn't find a replacement for it or I had said so. If you've got Xposed, there's [App Settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings) (also [see here](//www.guidingtech.com/46370/per-app-settings-xposed-module/) for details), but it's of the same age – though [XDA has a slightly never version](//forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=61696098&postcount=1847).